# How to scan for BLE device only using android app?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an app in which i want that when i click in scan button it will only scan for BLEs not android phone's bluetooth, so is there any permission or dependency to scan only for BLE's not centrals.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for avoiding Phone:

```
    if (device.getBluetoothClass().getMajorDeviceClass() != BluetoothClass.Device.Major.PHONE) {
        // do something
    }
```

Pls see `BluetoothClass.Device.Major` and choose what u want

```
    public static class Major {
        private static final int BITMASK           = 0x1F00;
        public static final int MISC              = 0x0000;
        public static final int COMPUTER          = 0x0100;
        public static final int PHONE             = 0x0200;
        public static final int NETWORKING        = 0x0300;
        public static final int AUDIO_VIDEO       = 0x0400;
        public static final int PERIPHERAL        = 0x0500;
        public static final int IMAGING           = 0x0600;
        public static final int WEARABLE          = 0x0700;
        public static final int TOY               = 0x0800;
        public static final int HEALTH            = 0x0900;
        public static final int UNCATEGORIZED     = 0x1F00;
    }
```